# Remove Firebase listener doesn't work Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I'm adding an event value listener to a reference and when I want to remove it, but it doesn't work.

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    stateListener =dbReference.stateRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
           //there is my functions
        })
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    dbReference.stateRef.removeEventListener(stateListener)
    Log.d("My_TAG", "$stateListener ")
}
```

This is the only place I'm adding the event.

after editing (still don't work)

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    stateListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        //One of the phone got flipped
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
        }

    }
    dbReference.stateRef.addValueEventListener(stateListener)

}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    Log.d("Life", "onStop")
    dbReference.stateRef.removeEventListener(stateListener)
}
```

Comment: add this inside onstart(), mReference.addValueEvenListener(stateListener);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to remove a listener, you first need to create it and then attach it to a `DatabaseReference` object.

```
val valueEventListener = ValueEventListener() {
    //override fun onDataChange
    //override fun onCancelled
}
dbReference.stateRef.addValueEventListener(eventListener)
```

So to remove the listener, you need to do it accordingly to the life-cycle of your activity like this:

```
dbReference.stateRef.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

- If you have added the listener in `onStart` you have to remove it in `onStop`.
- If you have added the listener in `onResume` you have to remove it in `onPause`.
- If you have added the listener in `onCreate` you have to remove it in `onDestroy`.

But remember `onDestroy` is not always called.

Comment: there is no error it's just doesn't remove the listener

Comment: In which place are trying ti remove it?

Comment: On the onStop method.

Comment: And why I are saying that the listener is still active of calling `dbReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);`?

Comment: How do you verify that is still active? Why do you think so?

Comment: Because when i change the data on the database its change on the phone as well

Comment: How can you see this? When onStop() is called, you supposed to have your activity stoped so you cannot see the activity anymore. If you restart the activity, onStart() is called again, and the listtener is again attached. So you can see all the changes.

Comment: i have three activities,i listen to an event from the second activity and when it change i go to the third activity, and when i stop the third activity i go back to the first activity, but when i change the data on the database it goes from the first activity to the third activity

Comment: If you listen in your second activity, then you must stop listening also in the second acitity. You say that you are stopping the third. Please be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

`addValueEventListener` doesn't return anything. You just created the listener anonymously. Therefore, your `stateListener` isn't referring to your listener.

Change your code as below:

```
class YourClassName:Activity(){    
private lateinit var statelistener: ValueEventListener

override fun onStart() {
    stateListener = ValueEventListener {
        [...]
    }
    dbReference.stateRef.addValueEventListener(stateListener)
}


override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    dbReference.stateRef.removeEventListener(stateListener)
    Log.d("My_TAG", "$stateListener ")
}
}
```

Now, your unsubscribe code should work. I am not very comfortable with Kotlin yet so pardon the syntax issues but the code above should work.

Comment: Give the stateListener class scope. Right now it is scoped to method.